# Burninate or rename [common]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, retag-request

The [common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/common) tag has 240 questions. It has no tag wiki.

- [16 of these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcommon%5D+fortran+is%3Aq) are about Fortran, and probably Fortran `common` blocks.
- [14 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[common]+apache+is%3Aq) look like they're about [apache-commons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-commons), which already has its own set of tags.
- [One question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[common]+%22common+js%22+is%3Aq) is about [commonjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/commonjs).
- The rest mostly seem to be tagged [common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/common) because they contain the word “common” somewhere in the question.

I don’t know if there needs to be a tag for Fortran `common` blocks, but the word “common” surely doesn’t need its own tag. If we do create a new tag, the tag could be renamed to [fortran-common-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran-common-block) for use with Fortran. If we want a [fortran-common-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran-common-block) tag, then I found another [28 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=-%5Bcommon%5D%20fortran%20%22common%20block%22%20is%3Aq) about `common` blocks that aren’t tagged [common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/common).

Comment: I guess, all those [common] tagged questions have nothing in common.

Comment: If common blocks are only in Fortran, shouldn't it be [fortran-common-block]?  I don't think that is too long.

Comment: i fixed the common js usage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 16 of these questions are about Fortran, and probably Fortran `common` blocks.

I've created the [fortran-common-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran-common-block) tag as suggested; after retagging these and others, it consists of 41 questions. Feel free to create a tag wiki if you wish.

> 14 questions look like they're about [apache-commons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-commons), which already has its own set of tags.

Manually cleaned up and retagged.

> One question is about [commonjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/commonjs).

[Fixed.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286085/burninate-or-rename-common?cb=1#comment155824_286085)

> The rest mostly seem to be tagged [common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/common) because they contain the word “common” somewhere in the question.

With the help of a few scripts, I've removed [common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/common) from all 240 questions and cleaned them up.

<sub>Also, for whatever reason, an unusually high number of questions tagged [common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/common) ended with "Thanks!" – just an interesting tidbit.</sub>